# Error PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I just want to show USU_USERS table between a declare procedure but it's shows this error when I try to compile

```
 DECLARE

 ID_UNICO VARCHAR(200) := 'H3LP';

 BEGIN
    
   DECLARE
          VID VARCHAR2(200);
          VID_USER VARCHAR2(200);
   BEGIN
          VID := ID_UNICO;
          VID_USER := 'SOPORTE';
 
          USR_SP_USERS.CREATE(
            VID => VID,
            VID_USER => VID_USER,
          );
   END;
        
    SELECT * from USU_USERS;

 END;
```

> NOTE : THIS TABLE HAS MORE THAN ONE ROWS.

Comment: Based upon how PL/SQL works, there is no place for the output to go. If you want output on the console and you're executing this as a "script", then remove the `BEGIN` and `END;`.

Comment: Sorry , I updated the post . I need to show the tables on the output whose are inside a DECLARE procedure

Comment: If you must use PL/SQL to print the output to the console, then have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56262713/1707353) and its answers. You can also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37567293/1707353).

Comment: The three queries are guaranteed to produce (C) 0 or more rows

Comment: "This is an example" - it is a very bad example, unfortunately. Your example should demonstrate the need to do "something" in PL/SQL, such as complicated processing, etc. In any case, it is almost certain that you will need to execute a SQL statement outside the PL/SQL block (and, therefore, the block will not be anonymous). Most common approach is to create a table function (a function that returns a table of some sort); then, in a standard SQL statement, you select "from that function" (really, from its table output). Your question, exactly as asked, makes no sense.

Comment: Ok , sorry for the bad example , I fixed it .

Answer (score 1):

PL/SQL is a server-side language only, and as such there's no way to "show" the results of a SELECT statement anywhere. Your SELECT statement needs to put the values it retrieves from the database into a variable or variables. Let's try to give you something which will work:

```
DECLARE
  strID_UNICO   VARCHAR(200) := 'H3LP';
  strVID        VARCHAR2(200);
  strVID_USER   VARCHAR2(200);

  rowUSU_USERS  USU_USERS%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  strVID := strID_UNICO;
  strVID_USER := 'SOPORTE';

  USR_SP_USERS.CREATE(VID      => strVID,
                      VID_USER => strVID_USER);
        
  SELECT *
    INTO rowUSU_USERS
    FROM USU_USERS;
END;
```

Note that if the table USU_USERS has more than one row in it this code will fail. Assuming, though, that USU_USERS has only a single row in it, you could then use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` to output the various fields in `rowUSU_USERS`.